# Variable is not saving after subprogram

Tags: python-3.x

I have been given a school project to create an interactive menu that allows a theoretical restaurant employee to input the items that a customer wants and output the table and the cost
(the first number is the table, second and above is the menu items)

But for some reason, in process() the cost is just getting outputted as 0, even though in the debug you can see that it is processing the cost fine.

```py
## -- Setup -- ##
Table = 0 # Used to display what table an order comes from
Menu = ["All day (Large)", "All day (Small)", "Hot Dog", "Burger", "Cheese burger", "Chicken goujons", "Fries", "Salad", "Milkshake",
    "Soft drinks", "Still Water", "Sparkling water"] # Menu Items, if statements will be used for the prices
MenuPrice = ["5.50", "3.50", "3.00", "4.00", "4.25", "3.50", "1.75","2.20", "1.30", "0.90", "0.90"]

## -- Main -- ##
# Order Input
i = input("Enter Table and Order number (Seperate with comma): ") # Order Input

# Order Processing
Order = i.split(",") # Splits the list where there is ","
Orderlen = len(Order)
Table = Order[0] # This is for displaying what table the order will go on
Table = int(Table) # Converting Table from a str to an int

global ii, Food, Cost, CostAdd
ii = 0 # Variable to complete a liner search through the order list
Food = [] # For displaying the food
Cost = 0 # For displaying the cost
CostAdd = 0 # Adds to Cost

def Process(ii, Cost, CostAdd): # Compiles the Order
    ii = ii + 1
    if ii == Orderlen:
        return Cost
        pass
    else:
        Pointer = Order[ii]
        Pointer = int(Pointer)
        Pointer = Pointer - 1 # Syncs input with the Diners Menu
        Food.append(Menu[Pointer])
        CostAdd = MenuPrice[Pointer]
        CostAdd = float(CostAdd)
        Cost = Cost + CostAdd
        print(f"Cost: {Cost}, CostAdd: {CostAdd}")

        Process(ii, Cost, CostAdd)
Process(ii, Cost, CostAdd)

# Order Output
print(f"NEW  Cost: {Cost}, CostAdd: {CostAdd}")
print(f"{Food} for Table: {Table}") # Displays what food is going to what table
print(f"This will cost: {Cost}")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide a [mre]. To start, you haven't given any example input.

Comment: BTW UpperCamelCase should be reserved for class names. Variables should be snake_case.

Comment: Did you intend and forget to *store* the ``Cost`` calculated inside ``Process``, perhaps? ``Cost`` inside ``Process`` is a local variable, independent of the global ``Cost`` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this gets you the output you were looking for or at least will help you in the right direction:

```
Table = 0 # Used to display what table an order comes from
Menu = ["All day (Large)", "All day (Small)", "Hot Dog", "Burger", "Cheese burger", "Chicken goujons", "Fries", "Salad", "Milkshake",
    "Soft drinks", "Still Water", "Sparkling water"] # Menu Items, if statements will be used for the prices
MenuPrice = ["5.50", "3.50", "3.00", "4.00", "4.25", "3.50", "1.75","2.20", "1.30", "0.90", "0.90"]

## -- Main -- ##
# Order Input
i = input("Enter Table and Order number (Seperate with comma): ") # Order Input

# Order Processing
Order = i.split(",") # Splits the list where there is ","
Orderlen = len(Order)
Table = Order[0] # This is for displaying what table the order will go on
Table = int(Table) # Converting Table from a str to an int

global ii, Food, Cost, CostAdd
ii = 0 # Variable to complete a liner search through the order list
Food = [] # For displaying the food
Cost = 0 # For displaying the cost
CostAdd = 0 # Adds to Cost

def Process(ii, Cost, CostAdd): # Compiles the Order
    while 1:
        ii = ii + 1
        if ii == Orderlen:
            return Cost,CostAdd
        else:
            Pointer = Order[ii]
            Pointer = int(Pointer)
            Pointer = Pointer - 1 # Syncs input with the Diners Menu
            Food.append(Menu[Pointer])
            CostAdd = MenuPrice[Pointer]
            CostAdd = float(CostAdd)
            Cost = CostAdd
            print(f"Cost: {Cost}, CostAdd: {CostAdd}")

Cost,CostAdd = Process(ii, Cost, CostAdd)

# Order Output
print(f"NEW  Cost: {Cost}, CostAdd: {CostAdd}")
print(f"{Food} for Table: {Table}") # Displays what food is going to what table
print(f"This will cost: {Cost}")
```